# Adding an XQuery function library to BaseX

Tags: xquery, basex

How can I add an XQuery function library to a BaseX database I have running in standalone mode via the command line? Specifically I want to add the FunctX library which I have downloaded the functions into a text file.

Comment: The BaseX documentation should help you: http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Repository#Installation

Comment: Awesome, I was looking under the library docs which didn't help at all. Thanks!